# ObjectiveC <Custom UI> Share Extension Cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

this could be something silly but I have this Share `NSExtension` implemented for my app which is holding custom UI built in `MainInterface.storyboard` (image attached). Now the question is, how do I back out of it?

I've tried:

- `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
- `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
- `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

..but it does not work;

The only way I got it to exit is:

- @throw @""; (which I don't even think will pass Apple's submission validation..)

What am I missing?

Thanks.

[image: MainInterface.storyboard]

Answer (score 5):

With extensions you need to tell the system that you're finished.

It will be something like:
`[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:nil completionHandler:nil];`